# Как преобразовать указатель на функцию-член в указатель на обычную функцию

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, преобразование-типов, анонимная-функция

Есть класс, внутри которого есть словарь Functions с парами: string : double(*)(double argument)
Помимо передачи обычных функций, нужно иметь возможность передавать туда указатель на метод этого же класса.
Со вторым пунктом появились проблемы, как известно, нет способа привести указатель на метод к указателю на функцию, поэтому вот как я поступил:

```
void smp::Oper::addFunction(std::string name, Oper* exp) //
{
    ps->Functions[name] = [exp](double argument) { return exp->getResult(argument); };
}
```

Мне казалось это красивым решением, но MSVS была со мной не согласна.
Говорила, что:Ошибка (активно)  E0413   не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "lambda []double (double argument)->double" в "smp::Function"

Дело в том, что как только лямбда захватывает из внешнего контекста что-либо, такое преобразование перестаёт работать (дело именно в захвате, это я точно знаю). В данном случае нужно захватить указатель exp, чтобы вызвать у него метод getResult, который и нужно добавить.

Я решил пойти иным путём, а именно вот таким:

```
template <typename CL>
double closureToFunction(double x) {
    CL cl;
    return cl(x);
}

void smp::Oper::addFunction(std::string name, Oper* exp)
{
    auto lam = [exp](double argument) { return exp->getResult(argument); };
    Function func = closureToFunction<decltype(lam)>;
    ps->Functions[name] = func;
}
```

Подумал, может мне получится обойти это всё и сделать сначала лямбду, потом промежуточную функцию с нужной сигнатурой и вот её уже добавить в словарь.
Студия перестала меня ругать, это уже радовало. Делаю рантайм и получаю:
Ошибка  C3497   нельзя сформировать экземпляр лямбда-выражения

Скажите, позволяет ли язык С++ решить мою проблему?
Как мне сделать так, чтобы в этот словарь можно было передать и указатель на метод, и на функцию?

Comment: А вызывать вы их потом как планируете? Как определять будете - это метод, ему для вызова нужен объект (кстати, какой?), а это просто функция, эта обойдется...

Comment: "А вызывать вы их потом как планируете?" - Впоследствии при необходимости экземпляр класса будет обращаться к словарю Functions, искать в нём название нужной функции и вызывать эту функцию, передавая в неё double и получая назад double

Comment: вообще, если вы хотите использовать метод как функцию, то вы можете использовать `std::bind` с `this` и `std::placeholders`. Но учтите, что объекты не должны быть уничтожены

Comment: " то вы можете использовать std::bind с this и std::placeholders", спасибо, сейчас узнаю об этом побольше

Comment: "Делаю рантайм" - это compile time. Нестатический метод класса с сигнатурой `double method(double argument)` будет принимать два аргумента и ни при каких обстоятельствах не может быть преобразован к указателю на функцию с одним аргументом. Анонимный объект, создаваемый лямбда-выражением `[exp](double argument)` по-прежнему будет реализовывать такой же нестатический метод c двумя аргументами. Можно использовать `std::function`, можно переделать указатель в указатель на функцию с двумя аргументами, можно сделать санки.

Comment: "Можно использовать std::function" - я правильно понимаю, что с помощью этой оболочки я смогу ссылаться на любые функции с общей сигнатурой?

Comment: Да, но это самый неэффективный метод.

Comment: Благодарю, надеюсь, что он в таком случае не единственный.